# Self-adjoint implies continuous (by elementary means)

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there an elementary way of proving that if $T:H\to H$ is a self-adjoint, ie: $(Tx,y)=(x,Ty)$ , operator between the same Hilbert space $H$ then, $T$ is continuous ?

By elementary, I mean a proof which does not use any big/powerful theorem as Banach-Steinhaus or the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: But wikipedia mentions "closed graph theorem" and uniform boundedness principle" for the proof. Both were excluded in the question.

Comment: @gerw You are right, I have deleted my comment

Answer (score 2):

Any proof must rely on the completeness of the underlying space because there are simple examples of symmetric operators that are not continuous. For example, let $X$ be the linear space of all finite linear combinations of $e^{inx}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ with the usual $L^2$ inner product. The differentiation operator
$$
              A = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}
$$
is defined and symmetric on $X$. However, $A$ is definitely not continuous because $0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$ are eigenvalues. So, any proof of what you want must rely on completeness of the underlying space. It is easy to show that a symmetric operator is closed by considering sequences. So the natural candidate for a proof of what you want is the Closed Graph Theorem. I don't think there's much of a way around the theorems you exclude.